# Виртуальные функции при виртуальном наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, множественное-наследование, виртуальная-функция

```
struct A {
    virtual void f(){}
};

struct B1: virtual A {
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct B2 : virtual A {
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct C :B1,B2 {

};
```

Ошибка  C2250   C: неоднозначное наследование "void A::f(void)".
Что это значит?

Comment: Ох, это надо пересказывать целый раздел 11.6.2 стандарта... Посмотрите его здесь: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4820.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если очень вкратце... В стандарте сказано -

> Виртуальная функция-член C::vf классового объекта S называется конечным перекрывателем (final overrider), если только самый производный класс (1.8), для которого S является подобъектом базового класса (если такой есть), не объявляет и не наследует другую функцию-член, перекрывающую vf. **Если виртуальная функция-член подобъекта базового класса имеет в производном классе более одного конечного перекрывателя, программа считается неправильной.**

Ессли наследование *невиртуальное* - то в вашем примере конечный перекрыватель для `B1::A::f` есть `B1::f`, а конечный перекрыватель для `B2::A::f` есть `B2::f`. Т.е. каждая виртуальная функция имеет один перекрыватель (ну, или для каждого конечного перекрывателя есть своя виртуальная функция.

А вот если оно виртуальное - то такая функция `A::f` единственная, а перекрывателей у нее два. Срабатывает выделенное выше.

Но стоит добавить свой перекрыватель в `C` -

```
struct C :B1,B2 {
    virtual void f() {}
};
```

как неоднозначность пропадает.

Примерно так...